# Prolog doesn't return the correct query (to my knowledge) when added the (X \= Y) clause

Tags: prolog

Knowledge base:

```
loves(vincent,mia).
loves(marcellus,mia).
loves(pumpkin,honey_bunny).
loves(honey_bunny,pumpkin).


jealous(X,Y) :-
    X \= Y,
    loves(X,Z),
    loves(Y,Z).
```

Now I type `jealous(vincent, X).` , it returns `false`. Shouldn't it be `X = marcellus`, since marcellus is not equal to vincent but they both love mia? Am I missing something?

Comment: Need to consider at what point the variables are instantiated. `dif(X, Y)` is the safe alternative. Another thing to bear in mind: X and Y are too-common variable names - sometimes it's better to choose names which are more *meaningful* (and predicate names). E.g. is X jealous of Y, or is Y jealous of X, can it be made more pleasant to read?

Comment: Wouldn't this make more sense if vincent is jealous of marcellus because vincent loves mia, but mia loves *marcellus* and *not* vincent? I.e. a couple of changes from your current logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `jealous(vincent, Y).`, it tries to see if `vincent` is not equal to `Y`. However, `Y` is uninstantiated at this point as there has been no possibility to pick from.

An easy fix is to place the `X \= Y.` at the end of your predicate like so:

```
jealous(X,Y) :-
    loves(X,Z),
    loves(Y,Z),
    X \= Y.
```

This gives the intended answer: `X = marcellus.`

An easy way to see what is going on next time is to run `trace.`; this lets you debug your code easily. (This is the case for SWI-Prolog, not sure about other versions).

Comment: Beginners should be guided towards `dif(X, Y)`, i.e. declarative. Rather than the gotcha-prone and imperative `X \= Y`.